# zoom in a CDF figure

Tags: r, zooming

I have the below figure shows cdf. I am wondering how can I zoom in to show better the difference between four lines in the left upper part of the figure.

[image]

Comment: Are you using ggplot? If so, look at `ylim` and `coord_cartesian`.

Comment: Yes I am using ggplot2 @PeterDee

Comment: Then look at [coord_cartesian](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/coord_cartesian.html)

Comment: thanks. It works but is there any possibility to zoom it so that that part comes out of the figure. I like to have the whole and the zoom part both in the same figure. @PeterDee

Comment: Have a look at section 8.4.1 in Hadley's ggplot2 book. The solution boils down to saving your zoomed in version as a separate plot, defining a viewport on your larger plot, and printing the smaller one to the viewport. For these types of figures you need to use `pdf()` c.s. because `ggsave()` doesn't work with viewports.

Comment: Thanks @PaulLemmens - didn't know that you could do that. I added an example below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `coord_cartesian` to zoom in. I don't know what you mean by having the zoom part and the whole in the same figure. If you want to have them side by side, you can use the `multiplot` function found in the Cookbook for R [page](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2)/). For example:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(rnorm(100, 0, 3), rnorm(100, 0, 10)),
                 g = gl(2, 100))

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, colour = g)) + stat_ecdf()
p1 <- p
p2 <- p + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(.75, 1)) 
multiplot(p1, p2)
```

[image: multiplot]

**Edit**
Based on @Paul Lemmens' comment, you can use `grid`'s `viewport` function in the following way:

```
pdf("~/Desktop/foo.pdf", width = 6, height = 6)
subvp <- viewport(width = .4, height = .4, x = .75, y = .25)
p1
print(p2, vp = subvp)
dev.off()
```

which gives the following output - adjust the details for your specific example:
[image: viewport figure]